# Updating UI from broadcastreceiver

Tags: android

I'm using the bump android sdk. I have a broadcast receiver and i would like to update some elements from my ui depending on different intent filters. for example

```
else if (action.equals(BumpAPIIntents.NOT_MATCHED)) {
                Log.i("Bump Test", "Not matched.");
                BumpTest inst = BumpTest.instance();
                if(inst != null) {

                    inst.UpdateMyText("testing");
                }
```

Problem is even though in logcat i can see the log entry the textview update method doesnt seem to be called

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: what is "bump android sdk"? http://bu.mp/? and updating UI from broadcast receiver is wrong. Your app is not guaranted to be running when your onReceive() is called

Comment: yes. that's the sdk i'm referring to. What would be a good way to change a textview then from that event (NOT_MATCHED)

Comment: I should just check if the app is running and then myapp.this.UpdateMyText("testing") ?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't allowed to update the UI from other threads (like the one that calls the BroadcastReceiver). You'll have to use a simple [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class. It was created for the sole purpose of updating the UI after performing actions that will take a long time to complete. It's a good idea to put things like requesting resources from the internet in an AsyncTask because it doesn't block the UI thread from executing. The nice side effect is it calls a function in your main program when it's done, and this call is done on the UI thread.